# How to simplify my SQL requests?

Tags: mysql, sql, refactoring

I have two tables here. One is `Items` and other is `Parts`.

`Items` have a `part_id` and `Parts` have an `item_id`.

When a user press on the submit button from the `ItemDetail` view, data are sent to the server and inserted into those two tables.

Here is how my code works :

1. Insert to `Items` table first and get the `id` of new `Item` data
2. Insert to `Parts` table with this `item_id` and other `Part` data
3. Update to `Items` table using new `part_id`

But can I write those three SQL requests in just one request ?

Here is the structure of my tables:

***Items***

```
Field | Type | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
| id | int(10) unsigned | NO | PRI | NULL | auto_increment |
| name | varchar(255) | YES | | NULL | |
| price | int(11) | YES | | NULL | |
| part_id | int(10) unsigned | YES | | NULL | |
| type | varchar(255) | YES | | NULL | |
```

***Parts***

```
Field | Type | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
| id | int(10) unsigned | NO | PRI | NULL | auto_increment |
| item_id | int(10) unsigned | NO | | NULL | |
| name | varchar(255) | NO | | NULL | |
| number | varchar(255) | YES | | NULL | |
```

Comment: I suppose 1 item can have multiple parts? In that case, get rid of the `part_id` from the `Items` table. You can get multiple `part_id`'s so there is no way to save it like that. Since you already have a reverence from the part's table, you can make the link that way. This way you can get rid of step 3.

Comment: thank you for your comment. items and parts relation is 1:1. Parts must have item_id but Items doesn't have to have part_id.

Comment: What @Ivar says still stand even for the situation you describe. Are you sure that they have a 1:1 relation? can't one part be used in multiple items? what kind of parts/items are you talking about?

Comment: thank you very much for your comment. I am not using sqls for make this code. I use sailsjs waterline and knexjs for this. so sailsjs migrated table has those tables. sailsJS waterline make those foreign key relationship by Model. and I apologize for my bad English.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have 2 tables pointing to each other like this, only one of the tables should have a foreign key, not both.

Then what you are looking for is this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commit.html

Transactions make sure that either all queries are executed, or if there is an error somewhere all changes will be reverted.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the logic you are using, you are doing it correctly.

As they are two separate tables you will need to do two separate insert statements in SQL. Of course you can use a stored procedure so that you only need to call one item in your code and the SP will do two inserts.

A question here is what code are you using? If you are using something like entity framework and your relationships are defined between your elements such as

**Items**

*-Field 1*

*-Parts (FK)* `List<Parts>`

That would work, but looking at what you have tagged I am guessing your not using a ASP language?? If you are let me know and I may have a better solution for you.

Comment: thank you for your comment. I am using javascript. nodejs and sailjs framework. entity framework is waterline and knex.

Comment: Not knowing that framework, I did a quick look up and saw it is quite similar to how EntityFramework functions. http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/associations/one-to-many shows some examples of have List like objects in your table structure.